# Delete particular files in all subdirectories of a directory in linux

Tags: linux

I want to delete all the audio files which are not in ".wav" format from a directory and all its sub-directories.

My script here doesn't work-

```
for file in /home/deepthought/Music/genres/*/; do rm $file not in *.wav; done
```

What should be the correct routine?

Comment: Do you care about the actual format, or are you just wanting to delete based on the filename?  Don't judge a file's format by its name!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
find /home/deepthought/Music/genres -not -name '*.wav' -print
```

to list the files and verify that they are the ones you want to delete.  Then

```
find /home/deepthought/Music/genres -not -name '*.wav' -delete
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `find` command instead,

```
find /home/deepthought/Music/genres -not -name "*.wav" -type f -delete
```

Comment: A `not` operator would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Try find command with -exec commandline like:

```
find /home/deepthought/Music/genres -type f -not -name "*.wav" -exec rm -f {} \;
```